# Telerik MVC Star Rating, resize stars

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, telerik

How do you correctly resize the Telerik MVC Start Rating control.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Rating()
  .Min(1)
  .Max(5)
  .Value(i.SavedRating)
  .Readonly(true)
  .Label(false)
  .Enabled(false)
  .Precision("half"))
```

I have a very basic control, but when attempting to resize the stars using the **.k-icon** class the some start are not perfectly horizontal.

```
.k-icon {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

I have also tried using itemTemplates but i still get the same result.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9p9g.png)

Comment: If I look at the documentation of https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/rating/events and increasing the font size for ".k-rating-container .k-rating-item .k-icon" works for me but obviously not for you. Check if the wrapper that is wrapping these elements has something Weird on them

Comment: Nothing fancy happening in the wrapper, just a bootstrap col-12 container

Answer (score 0):

So changing the size of the stars is achieved by setting the font-size of **.k-icon**, but that messed up my layout slightly.

I sorted it out by setting the font size of the **.k-rating** = 0px;

```
.ratingFilterItem .k-rating-item .k-icon {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.k-rating {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

Then you can just play around with the margins and paddings as required.